# How to sort snapshots by creation time?

Tags: vagrant, snapshot

I have list of snapshot for my machine.

```
$ vagrant snapshot list
```

```
fresh
java
last
node
sdkman
```

By default they are sorted alphabetically.

Is there way to **sort snapshots by creation date** or to **get snapshot creation date**?